# SAS: When using "by" statement, what does "var1 = ." mean in output?

Tags: sas

Let's say I have some simple code like what is below.

```
 proc sort; by  var1 var2;
 run;

 proc gplot;
 plot y*x ;
 by var1 var2;
 run;
```

In the output, there are a bunch of graphs. In addition to all the combinations of values of var1 and var2, I also get charts where `var1=.` in combination with each value of var2 (etc).  Does the `var1=.` mean the plot is including all values of var1?  Or data where var1 is somehow blank? Or something else?  Is there a way I can get these to not print out (i.e. if I want exactly as many plots as there are combinations of var1 and var2)?  It's not a big deal for only two variables, but creates a lot of extra plots to scroll through when using more variables.

Thanks!

Comment: I looks like some values of 'var1' are missing values...

Comment: Are var1 and var2 character or numeric variables?

Comment: @Glen They are numeric

Comment: Hmmm.. I don't think there are values missing because this happens no matter what variables I use (including var2).  I think it is just collapsing across all values of the variable.  But, I would like to figure out how to get it to not do that.

Comment: Could you post a subset of your data to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It the case of `gplot` it means what it says, that the graph in question is limited to observations where `var1=.`, i.e. where `var1` is missing. I tried but was unable to break this behavior, and as far as I can see the manual doesn't specify any other behavior.

If these graphs are unwanted then a simple `where` statement at any of several places would remove them. E.g. place this somewhere before `proc gplot`:

```
data;
    set;
    where not missing (var1);
run;
```

If these graphs are unexpected then I advise you to look through your data and programs to see if something went wrong somewhere. For me personally unexpected missing data tends to indicate I misspelled a variable name somewhere.

For a more specific answer you'll have to give more specific information.